# I want an object(bird) rotate right when falling

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

There is my code:
I watched a tutorial on youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dWtoB3J1YTg).
I tried to follow the steps, but I probably misspelled something because the *rotating right while falling* thing is not working for me :( 
Please help! **If you need more information about this just ask me!**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class BirdMovement : MonoBehaviour {

    Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;
    public Vector3 gravity;
    public Vector3 flapVelocity;
    public float maxSpeed = 5f;
    public float forwardSpeed = 1f;

    bool didFlap = false;

    // Do Graphic & Input updates here
    void Update() {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            didFlap = true;
                }
           }

    // Do physics engine updates here
    void FixedUpdate () {
        velocity.x = forwardSpeed;
        velocity += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

        if (didFlap == true) {
            didFlap = false;
            if(velocity.y < 0) 
                velocity.y = 0;

            velocity += flapVelocity;
                }

        velocity = Vector3.ClampMagnitude (velocity, maxSpeed);

        transform.position += velocity * Time.deltaTime;

        float angle = 0;
        if(velocity.y < 0) {
            angle = Mathf.Lerp (0, -90, velocity.y / maxSpeed);
        }

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (0,0,angle);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the tutorial this is what my code looks like. You are missing the `Animator`

```
public class BirdMovement : MonoBehaviour 
{
    Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;
    public float flapSpeed    = 100f;
    public float forwardSpeed = 1f;
    bool didFlap = false;
    Animator animator;
    public bool dead = false;
    float deathCooldown;
    public bool godMode = false;

    void Start () 
    {
        animator = transform.GetComponentInChildren<Animator>();

        if(animator == null) 
            Debug.LogError("Failed to find animator!");
    }

    void Update() 
    {
        if(dead) 
        {
            deathCooldown -= Time.deltaTime;

            // This should be an AND but this is how it comes in tutorial.
            if(deathCooldown <= 0) 
                if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) 
                    Application.LoadLevel( Application.loadedLevel );
        }

        else if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) 
           didFlap = true;
    }


    // Do physics engine updates here
    void FixedUpdate () 
    {
        if(dead)
            return;

        rigidbody2D.AddForce( Vector2.right * forwardSpeed );

        if(didFlap) {
            rigidbody2D.AddForce( Vector2.up * flapSpeed );
            animator.SetTrigger("DoFlap");

            didFlap = false;
        }

        if(rigidbody2D.velocity.y > 0)
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);

        else 
        {
            float angle = Mathf.Lerp (0, -90, (-rigidbody2D.velocity.y / 3f) );
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle);
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) {
        if(godMode)
            return;

        animator.SetTrigger("Death");
        dead = true;
        deathCooldown = 0.5f;
    }
}
```